# Can I save files/folders in NSSearchPathDirectory.ApplicationDirectory? NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory is not ideal for me

Tags: ios, swift

iOS 8.4 | Swift 2.1

When I was tried to create a new folder in `NSSearchPathDirectory.ApplicationDirectory`, I followed with this **error** on device (in simulator it did worked, though):

code:

```
let docuPath:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.ApplicationDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0])
ConstantsVO.imagePath = docuPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("imagegallery")
if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(ConstantsVO.imagePath.path!)
{
     do
     {
          try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(ConstantsVO.imagePath.path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
     }
     catch let error as NSError
     {
          NSLog("\(error.localizedDescription)")
     }
     catch
     {
          print("general error - \(error)", terminator: "\n")
     }
 }
```

error

> 2015-11-02 10:53:21.114 Elmo[218:5055] You don’t have permission to
>   save the file “imagegallery” in the folder “Applications”. fatal error:
>   'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “imagegallery” doesn’t
>   exist."
>   UserInfo={NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/48D90635-0D66-44C2-81CE-F67BAFDA819A/Applications/imagegallery,
>   NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/48D90635-0D66-44C2-81CE-F67BAFDA819A/Applications/imagegallery,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x16e7d540 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2
>   "No such file or directory"}}: file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.59/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 50

However, using `NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory` did worked for me and worked expectedly. But in my application, I've feature to share/import through iTunes, so I have the "***Application supports iTunes file sharing***" TRUE in my `info.plist` - this exposed `NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory` in iTunes. I don't want the files/folders that I'm saving through my app to be expose to the user in iTunes. Then where should I save the files/folders yet can able to use file sharing through iTunes by exposing `NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from this post is helpful:
[Path directory usable in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268299/path-directory-usable-in-ios)

> As far as I know only these are usable on iOS:
>
> `NSDocumentDirectory` is `Documents`/     (persistent, backed up, may
>   be visible in iTunes) `NSLibraryDirectory` is `Library`/
>   (persistent, backed up, not visibe to the user) `NSCachesDirectory` is
>   `Library/Caches/`     (not backed up, may be cleared by system)

Now after I'm using `NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory` the I'm having no `NSFileManager` error on device nor the directories/files I'm storing inside `NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory` are exposed to the users in iTunes sharing tab.

Great!